how to insert an icon into legend value
I am trying to insert an icon in the value field of the legend based on the last year sales value.
Data set :
[{
   country: "France",
   sales: 100000,
   lastYearSales: 90000,
},
{
   country: "Spain",
   sales: 160000,
   lastYearSales: 130000,
}]

where I have used sales as legend value.
I have the code here
Right now I have the legends looking like this

I need it to look like

Here, the triangle needs to be an icon and the text beside it % change from last year
